# Twilio Dial verb speaks number instead of dialing outbound

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am currently working from a `Twilio` sub account and a TwiML app attempting to start an outbound call from a web based client.

I am using the `Twilio`. Device in the browser to connect to a landline. I have a public end-point exposed (using ngrok) and the TwiML App is successfully configured to POST the call request to the endpoint. I am responding with `<Response><Say>Welcome to this call</Say><Dial>+1XXXXXXXXXX</Dial></Response>`. When the client "connects" the system simply speaks the message *and* the number instead of dialing it and then hangs up. This happens regardless of the Say verb being present.

We do have conference calling working between to phone numbers, but getting this web client to call outbound is giving us a little trouble.

```
[REQUEST PARAMETERS: {"ApplicationSid":["APxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"],"ApiVersion":["2010-04-01"],"agent":["3xxxxxxxxx"],"Called":[""],"Caller":["client:Anonymous"],"CallStatus":["ringing"],"CallSid":["CAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"],"To":["8xxxxxxxxx"],"From":["2xxxxxxxxx"],"Direction":["inbound"],"AccountSid":["ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]}]

[REQUEST HEADERS: {content-length=278, x-forwarded-proto=https, host=4dxxxxxxx.ngrok.io, content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8, connection=close, x-forwarded-for=xxx.xxx.229.114, cache-control=max-age=259200, x-twilio-signature=lflllCdXo004m0wRzw/efN0IAjg=, user-agent=TwilioProxy/1.1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, feel a like a newbie, but I had forgot to set the content type to one of the required `Content-Type` headers, `text/xml`, `text/html`, or `application/xml`. With the header in the response Twilio connects the call as expected.